# Firestore - Browser refresh listener and active connections clean-up issue

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

When I refresh my browser three times, I will end up with 3 active connections and 3 snapshot listeners (instead of 1 and 1) for a few minutes before it goes back down to 1 and 1. Is this normal behaviour?

I know that refreshing the browser should trigger a clean-up, but is it supposed to be delayed?

Furthermore, it is only one tab being refreshed three times, so even if the snapshot listener clean-up is delayed, shouldn't it still be one active connection at all times since only one app/user is connected to the database?

Lastly, since a browser refresh is considered the same as closing and opening a new instance of the app, a new connection should count as a new batch of reads and should not pull data from the local cache. This doesn't seem to be the case as my read count remained at 0 during browser refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a new page on the browser, all information from the previous page is flushed from memory, unless you explicitly pass it along.

It sounds like you see some lingering connections on the Firestore console, which is expected. It may take up to a few minutes before the dropped connection is also detected on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I am not passing any data along nor explicitly storing it locally. I have persistence enabled, but I was under the impression that a refresh would still flush the data from memory as mentioned and re-read all documents upon setting new snapshot listeners. Why does the read count not increase?

Comment: If you have local persistence enabled, the reads likely are coming fro the local cache - which is **not** flushed between page reloads (it'd be pretty useless otherwise) - and Firestore only charged when documents are read from the server.